# Error in typescript function- Function lacks ending return statement and return type does not include 'undefined'

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm getting error in the createBreadcrumbs function('Function lacks ending return statement and return type does not include 'undefined'.ts(2366)'). Please explain why i'm getting the error and how can i resolve it?

```
export class BreadcrumbComponent implements OnInit {

  static readonly ROUTE_DATA_BREADCRUMB = 'breadcrumb';
  readonly home = {icon: 'pi pi-home', url: 'home'};
  menuItems!: MenuItem[];

  constructor(private router: Router, private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.router.events
      .pipe(filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd))
      .subscribe(() => this.menuItems = this.createBreadcrumbs(this.activatedRoute.root));
  }

  private createBreadcrumbs(route: ActivatedRoute, url: string = '#', breadcrumbs: MenuItem[] = []): MenuItem[] {
    const children: ActivatedRoute[] = route.children;

    if (children.length === 0) {
      return breadcrumbs
    } 

    for (const child of children) {
      const routeURL: string = child.snapshot.url.map(segment => segment.path).join('/');
      if (routeURL !== '') {
        url += `/${routeURL}`;
      }

      const label = child.snapshot.data[BreadcrumbComponent.ROUTE_DATA_BREADCRUMB];
      if (label !== null || label !== undefined) {
        breadcrumbs.push({label, url});
      }

      return this.createBreadcrumbs(child, url, breadcrumbs);
    }
  
    
  }

}
```

Comment: It's exactly as the error says. `createBreadcrumbs` might not return a value at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the Typescript's compiler does not understand that if the length of the array is different from zero, it will surely enter the loan and return a value.

So, the simple soultion is this:

```js
  private createBreadcrumbs(route: ActivatedRoute, url: string = '#', breadcrumbs: MenuItem[] = []): MenuItem[] {
    const children: ActivatedRoute[] = route.children;

    for (const child of children) {
      const routeURL: string = child.snapshot.url.map(segment => segment.path).join('/');
      if (routeURL !== '') {
        url += `/${routeURL}`;
      }

      const label = child.snapshot.data[BreadcrumbComponent.ROUTE_DATA_BREADCRUMB];
      if (label !== null || label !== undefined) {
        breadcrumbs.push({label, url});
      }

      return this.createBreadcrumbs(child, url, breadcrumbs);
    }

    // if (children.length === 0)
    return breadcrumbs;
  }
```